# How can one receive android updates?

Tags: android-versions

How can one install android OS updates even when the manufacturer doesn't provide any? I have an android lollipop phone and wish to update it to marshmallow.

Answer (score -1):

The android update will be provided by OTA by the manufaturer itself.

Go to **Settings->About Phone->Check for Updates** in your android device.

Can you please share your device model name and number? and the current version of android?

Comment: Anand, that doesn't answer the question: "when the manufacturer doesn't provide any" contradicts with checking for OTA updates "by the manufacturer itself" :)

Comment: But this is the basic method to check for official updates right?

Comment: But that was not the question. The manufacturer doesn't provide an update just because you push a button. And if there is no update provided by the manufacturer, pushing the button won't find any. The question was how to update when the manufacturer does ***not*** provide any – and you answered how to do it when the manufacturer ***does*** provide an OTA update. No match here. The correct answer in such a case is finding a custom ROM matching the device – which cannot be done by pressing that button.